# Jquery mobile - onhashchange issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, hashchange

I am using `$.mobile` in my app. I must create my own routing system.
I bind observer on `hashchange` and I pull out interesting data from `location.hash`.
I have a problem  - `jQuery.mobile` removes the hash sign from `location.hash` if it has a slashes   ( e.g. from `'lalal/#controller/action/param'` to `'lalal/controller/action/param'` and `$.mobile` says in yellow box `Error Loading Page`.

I tried to unbind existing "hashchange" in first, but then pages not load automatically ( what I require ).

How to prevent changes of hash, but that jQuery must still load the page automatically( e.g. by its ID declared in element having `data-role='page'`)? . Below is a fragment of my router class: ( `Router.load` doesn't change `location.hash` )

```
__construct: function() {   

        var that = this; 
        $( window ).bind( "hashchange" , function( e ) {
            //e.stopImmediatePropagation()
            that.load( this.location.hash  ); 

        });  
    }
```

Comment: What version of jQM and jQuery are you running? as in RC1 and RC2 there where some bug fixes to hashchange

Comment: Do you mean the latest jQuery 1.7 and jQueryMobile RC3? Just to note jQuery 1.7 is not supported yet by jQM, so 1.6.4 is the version you should be running

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are fighting against the "pushState" plugin in jQuery Mobile added in Beta 3 (I believe). You can disable this plugin with the following code (used before you include the jQuery Mobile JavaScript file):

```
$(document).on('mobileinit', function () {
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
});
```

Check-out the documentation here (notice the "pushState Plugin" section): http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc3/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html

Comment: Disabling pushStateEnabled makes that hash sign  no longer  disappear from adress bar  - ok, but `$.mobile` still tries to load pages using ajax( only when hash contain slashes)  - even when  `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false`;of course with status 404 and jqm is firing page load error

Answer (score 0):

in your html after including jquery and **before** including jquery.mobile-1.x.y.js add:

```
<script>
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
        $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
});
</script>
```