# How to use jQuery Mobile for its touch event support only (no UI enhancements)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I’m working on a web app that has its own look and feel. I want to use jQuery Mobile for the touch events support only.

When I link jquery.mobile.min.js (without linking the css), then the layout of my page is broken.

How can I configure (initialize) jQuery Mobile to only use touch events support? Would I bind the events in the jQuery document ready hook since I'd not have any JQM page related event?

**Edit**

See this example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/redhotsly/JGgrw/. The html contains a `<button>` but jQuery Mobile created a `<span>` to its left. If you inspect the resulting markup (F12) you will see that jQuery Mobile also added a CSS class to my button.

**Edit:**

I need a solution where I'll not have modify the JQM script. I need to use the official script off a CDN.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you just want to bind to touch/gesture events I'd use jGestures instead:

http://jgestures.codeplex.com/

Nice little jquery plugin that I've used on projects before with a big range of events to bind to:

> **Available events:**
>
> **orientationchange** The device is turned clockwise or counterclockwise. This event is triggered by the device and might use
>   an internal gyroscope.
>
> **pinch** Is triggered during a pinch gesture (two fingers moving away from or towards each other).
>
> **rotate** Is triggered during a rotation gesture (two fingers rotating clockwise or counterclockwise).
>
> **swipemove** Is triggered during a swipe move gesture (finger(s) being moved around the device, e.g. dragging)
>
> **swipeone** Is triggered after a swipe move gesture with one touchpoint (one finger was moved around the device)
>
> **swipetwo** Is triggered after a swipe move gesture with two touchpoints (two fingers were moved around the device)
>
> **swipethree** Is triggered after a swipe move gesture with three touchpoints (three fingers were moved around the device)
>
> **swipefour** Is triggered after a swipe move gesture with four touchpoints (four fingers were moved around the device)
>
> **swipeup** Is triggered after an strict upwards swipe move gesture
>
> **swiperightup** Is triggered after a rightwards and upwards swipe move gesture
>
> **swiperight** Is triggered after a strict rightwards swipe move gesture
>
> **swiperightdown** Is triggered after a rig*htwards and downwards swipe move gesture
>
> **swipedown** Is triggered after a strict downwards swipe move gesture
>
> **swipeleftdown** Is triggered after a leftwards and downwards swipe move gesture
>
> **swipeleft** Is triggered after a strict leftwards swipe move gesture
>
> **swipeleftup** Is triggered after a leftwards and upwards swipe move gesture
>
> **tapone** Is triggered after a single (one finger) tap gesture
>
> **taptwo** Is triggered after a double (two finger) tap gesture
>
> **tapthree** Is triggered after a tripple (three finger) tap gesture
>
> **pinchopen** Is triggered when a pinchopen gesture (two fingers moving away from each other) occured and the touchpoints (fingers) are
>   removed the device.
>
> **pinchclose** Is triggered when a pinchclose gesture (two fingers moving towards each other) occured and the touchpoints (fingers) are
>   removed the device.
>
> **rotatecw** Is triggered when a clockwise rotation gesture (two fingers rotating clockwise) occured and the touchpoints (fingers) are
>   removed the device.
>
> **rotateccw** Is triggered when a counterclockwise rotation gesture (two fingers rotating counterclockwise) occured and the touchpoints
>   (fingers) are removed the device.

Comment: It looks like the answer to my question is _"it's not possible at this time, use another library"_. So that's what I'll do. Thanks.

Comment: this doesn't works on touch laptops or touch tablets with 1080p display ... strange :(

Comment: @Sijav May be worth reporting that to the jgestures guys :)

Answer (score 51):

If you want to use jQuery mobile for touch events only, add this piece of script **before** you load the jQuery mobile library:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){$.extend(  $.mobile , {autoInitializePage: false})});</script>
```

This prevents jquery mobile from initializing the page and touching the DOM, thus leaving your layout alone.

Comment: Hi eivers. This was a great help to me, but I was still frustrated because my site relies heavily on onhashchange for navigation and jQuery mobile was changing #'s to /. You might include a link to http://stackoverflow.com/a/8159996/3917091 which suggests adding `$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;`, because it is still on with mobileinit.

Comment: very great answer that helps to load only jquery mobile standard events.

Answer (score 33):

jQuery Mobile now has a Download Builder that lets you select only the parts that you want, in this case, you only need to select the Touch checkbox under the Event section.

http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/

Comment: I selected only the touch event but it's not doing anything

Answer (score 13):

jQM is now decoupled:

- http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/08/03/jquery-mobile-beta-2-released/

> **Widgets: Now decoupled for flexible builds**
>
> We’ve wanted to decouple all our widgets from the page plugin for a
>   long time now and we’re happy to announce that we finally landed this
>   change. So what exactly does decoupled mean anyway? Well, the
>   individual widgets and utilities have always been broken out into
>   separate script files. However, the page plugin was responsible for
>   handling the auto-initialization all of the official plugins found in
>   the markup at page creation. This situation made it impossible to
>   remove plugins you don’t need without causing errors, and generally
>   set a bad precedent for future widget additions.
>
> Now, pretty much all the UI widgets in the jQuery Mobile library are
>   completely decoupled so they can simply be deleted if not needed for a
>   particular project. This change allows you to dramatically reduce the
>   size of the library by only including the specific set of widgets or
>   features you need, in addition to the handful of required, core files.
>   While we still plan to do more decoupling and cleanup, the following
>   files are now decoupled and can safely be removed from the make file
>   before you do a custom build:
>
> - page header/content/footer
> - collapsible
> - controlgroup
> - fieldcontain
> - fixheaderfooter
> - button
> - checkboxradio
> - select
> - slider
> - textinput
> - links theming
> - listview
> - navbar
> - grid
>
> We will work on a dependency map because a few widgets rely on others
>   to work. For example, the button markup plugin is called by many of
>   the widgets above, so it can only be excluded but if you’re not using
>   any of the widgets that depend on buttons.
>
> We’re still working out our recommendations for mapping plugin
>   dependencies and decoupling things even further. Ultimately, this will
>   be surfaced in a download builder tool, so stay tuned!

You can head over to their GIT Repo and just download what you want:

- https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/tree/master/js

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to take a copy of the individual script files. I want to link to the official jquery mobile script on CDN.

Comment: I don't think they will release the decoupled libs on CDN, maybe jQM 1.1 will have this option which is scheduled to be released mid/late Feb.

Comment: Possibly, but even then, I’d really like to know how to initialize JQM in a way that it will not change the UI.

Comment: My answer lists the steps for creating your own JQM build with the events modules.

Answer (score 6):

Another new option is [jQuery-Mobile-Events](https://github.com/benmajor/jQuery-Mobile-Events), I've been struggle with this problem and only find this plugin useful.

The custom build from jQuery Mobile's Download Builder doesn't work for me. And [jGestures](http://jgestures.codeplex.com/) doesn't have the `taphold` event which I need.

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone else runs into this (and doesn't need the file off one of jQuery's CDNs), here are the steps I took to extract just the JQM event triggers:

1. `git clone git@github.com:jquery/jquery-mobile`
2. `cd jquery-mobile`
3. edit `js/jquery.mobile.js` in your favorite editor
4. replace the `define(...);` statement with `define(['./events/touch', './events/orientationchange']);`
5. `make`
6. your events-only JQM is now in `compiled/jquery.mobile.js` and `compiled/jquery.mobile.min.js`

Now you can use `$(el).tap(fn)` and the like without worrying about JQM highjacking your markup!

Comment: jQuery Mobile now has an online builder so you can roll your own custom build without the above steps. http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder

Answer (score 2):

taking care of this particular problem at init time is nearly impossible, your best bet is to use data-role="none" on the ui element that you do not want default styling to happen on as such:

```
<button type="button" data-role="none">Click Me!</button>​​​​​​​​​
```

check it out at http://jsfiddle.net/JGgrw/13/

Comment: I see. In order to apply this to my site I'd have to execute `$('*').attr('data-role', 'none');` before the `<script>` that includes JQM. It's not really practical.

Comment: believe me I'm in the middle of an apppication that is running into the same problem and if you try to infuse data-role via javascript it will still fail, save yourself some headaches and manually add that attribute to your ui elements or better look into templating with either jquery templates or mustache js to avoid the repetitiveness.

Answer (score 0):

Visit the link below and only Select TOUCH, Features that will be add are listed below each checkbox, so only select what you need and will possibly use.
CDN will always include all features and will slow down the as file size will be larger but not much. I have tested and is working :)

Working Example but (Full jQuery Mobile) with all features, simple use the one below or download the latest script of official website that is Custom:
https://codepen.io/binaryfever/pen/RGjKGP

http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/
Script below only supports the following features: 
Touch events including: **touchstart, touchmove, touchend, tap, taphold, swipe, swipeleft, swiperight, scrollstart, scrollstop.**

```
/*! jQuery Mobile _ Custom Touch Only - v1.4.5 | Copyright 2010, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */

(function(e,t,n){typeof define=="function"&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],function(r){return n(r,e,t),r.mobile}):n(e.jQuery,e,t)})(this,document,function(e,t,n,r){(function(e,t,n,r){function T(e){while(e&&typeof e.originalEvent!="undefined")e=e.originalEvent;return e}function N(t,n){var i=t.type,s,o,a,l,c,h,p,d,v;t=e.Event(t),t.type=n,s=t.originalEvent,o=e.event.props,i.search(/^(mouse|click)/)>-1&&(o=f);if(s)for(p=o.length,l;p;)l=o[--p],t[l]=s[l];i.search(/mouse(down|up)|click/)>-1&&!t.which&&(t.which=1);if(i.search(/^touch/)!==-1){a=T(s),i=a.touches,c=a.changedTouches,h=i&&i.length?i[0]:c&&c.length?c[0]:r;if(h)for(d=0,v=u.length;d<v;d++)l=u[d],t[l]=h[l]}return t}function C(t){var n={},r,s;while(t){r=e.data(t,i);for(s in r)r[s]&&(n[s]=n.hasVirtualBinding=!0);t=t.parentNode}return n}function k(t,n){var r;while(t){r=e.data(t,i);if(r&&(!n||r[n]))return t;t=t.parentNode}return null}function L(){g=!1}function A(){g=!0}function O(){E=0,v.length=0,m=!1,A()}function M(){L()}function _(){D(),c=setTimeout(function(){c=0,O()},e.vmouse.resetTimerDuration)}function D(){c&&(clearTimeout(c),c=0)}function P(t,n,r){var i;if(r&&r[t]||!r&&k(n.target,t))i=N(n,t),e(n.target).trigger(i);return i}function H(t){var n=e.data(t.target,s),r;!m&&(!E||E!==n)&&(r=P("v"+t.type,t),r&&(r.isDefaultPrevented()&&t.preventDefault(),r.isPropagationStopped()&&t.stopPropagation(),r.isImmediatePropagationStopped()&&t.stopImmediatePropagation()))}function B(t){var n=T(t).touches,r,i,o;n&&n.length===1&&(r=t.target,i=C(r),i.hasVirtualBinding&&(E=w++,e.data(r,s,E),D(),M(),d=!1,o=T(t).touches[0],h=o.pageX,p=o.pageY,P("vmouseover",t,i),P("vmousedown",t,i)))}function j(e){if(g)return;d||P("vmousecancel",e,C(e.target)),d=!0,_()}function F(t){if(g)return;var n=T(t).touches[0],r=d,i=e.vmouse.moveDistanceThreshold,s=C(t.target);d=d||Math.abs(n.pageX-h)>i||Math.abs(n.pageY-p)>i,d&&!r&&P("vmousecancel",t,s),P("vmousemove",t,s),_()}function I(e){if(g)return;A();var t=C(e.target),n,r;P("vmouseup",e,t),d||(n=P("vclick",e,t),n&&n.isDefaultPrevented()&&(r=T(e).changedTouches[0],v.push({touchID:E,x:r.clientX,y:r.clientY}),m=!0)),P("vmouseout",e,t),d=!1,_()}function q(t){var n=e.data(t,i),r;if(n)for(r in n)if(n[r])return!0;return!1}function R(){}function U(t){var n=t.substr(1);return{setup:function(){q(this)||e.data(this,i,{});var r=e.data(this,i);r[t]=!0,l[t]=(l[t]||0)+1,l[t]===1&&b.bind(n,H),e(this).bind(n,R),y&&(l.touchstart=(l.touchstart||0)+1,l.touchstart===1&&b.bind("touchstart",B).bind("touchend",I).bind("touchmove",F).bind("scroll",j))},teardown:function(){--l[t],l[t]||b.unbind(n,H),y&&(--l.touchstart,l.touchstart||b.unbind("touchstart",B).unbind("touchmove",F).unbind("touchend",I).unbind("scroll",j));var r=e(this),s=e.data(this,i);s&&(s[t]=!1),r.unbind(n,R),q(this)||r.removeData(i)}}}var i="virtualMouseBindings",s="virtualTouchID",o="vmouseover vmousedown vmousemove vmouseup vclick vmouseout vmousecancel".split(" "),u="clientX clientY pageX pageY screenX screenY".split(" "),a=e.event.mouseHooks?e.event.mouseHooks.props:[],f=e.event.props.concat(a),l={},c=0,h=0,p=0,d=!1,v=[],m=!1,g=!1,y="addEventListener"in n,b=e(n),w=1,E=0,S,x;e.vmouse={moveDistanceThreshold:10,clickDistanceThreshold:10,resetTimerDuration:1500};for(x=0;x<o.length;x++)e.event.special[o[x]]=U(o[x]);y&&n.addEventListener("click",function(t){var n=v.length,r=t.target,i,o,u,a,f,l;if(n){i=t.clientX,o=t.clientY,S=e.vmouse.clickDistanceThreshold,u=r;while(u){for(a=0;a<n;a++){f=v[a],l=0;if(u===r&&Math.abs(f.x-i)<S&&Math.abs(f.y-o)<S||e.data(u,s)===f.touchID){t.preventDefault(),t.stopPropagation();return}}u=u.parentNode}}},!0)})(e,t,n),function(e){e.mobile={}}(e),function(e,t){var r={touch:"ontouchend"in n};e.mobile.support=e.mobile.support||{},e.extend(e.support,r),e.extend(e.mobile.support,r)}(e),function(e,t,r){function l(t,n,i,s){var o=i.type;i.type=n,s?e.event.trigger(i,r,t):e.event.dispatch.call(t,i),i.type=o}var i=e(n),s=e.mobile.support.touch,o="touchmove scroll",u=s?"touchstart":"mousedown",a=s?"touchend":"mouseup",f=s?"touchmove":"mousemove";e.each("touchstart touchmove touchend tap taphold swipe swipeleft swiperight scrollstart scrollstop".split(" "),function(t,n){e.fn[n]=function(e){return e?this.bind(n,e):this.trigger(n)},e.attrFn&&(e.attrFn[n]=!0)}),e.event.special.scrollstart={enabled:!0,setup:function(){function s(e,n){r=n,l(t,r?"scrollstart":"scrollstop",e)}var t=this,n=e(t),r,i;n.bind(o,function(t){if(!e.event.special.scrollstart.enabled)return;r||s(t,!0),clearTimeout(i),i=setTimeout(function(){s(t,!1)},50)})},teardown:function(){e(this).unbind(o)}},e.event.special.tap={tapholdThreshold:750,emitTapOnTaphold:!0,setup:function(){var t=this,n=e(t),r=!1;n.bind("vmousedown",function(s){function a(){clearTimeout(u)}function f(){a(),n.unbind("vclick",c).unbind("vmouseup",a),i.unbind("vmousecancel",f)}function c(e){f(),!r&&o===e.target?l(t,"tap",e):r&&e.preventDefault()}r=!1;if(s.which&&s.which!==1)return!1;var o=s.target,u;n.bind("vmouseup",a).bind("vclick",c),i.bind("vmousecancel",f),u=setTimeout(function(){e.event.special.tap.emitTapOnTaphold||(r=!0),l(t,"taphold",e.Event("taphold",{target:o}))},e.event.special.tap.tapholdThreshold)})},teardown:function(){e(this).unbind("vmousedown").unbind("vclick").unbind("vmouseup"),i.unbind("vmousecancel")}},e.event.special.swipe={scrollSupressionThreshold:30,durationThreshold:1e3,horizontalDistanceThreshold:30,verticalDistanceThreshold:30,getLocation:function(e){var n=t.pageXOffset,r=t.pageYOffset,i=e.clientX,s=e.clientY;if(e.pageY===0&&Math.floor(s)>Math.floor(e.pageY)||e.pageX===0&&Math.floor(i)>Math.floor(e.pageX))i-=n,s-=r;else if(s<e.pageY-r||i<e.pageX-n)i=e.pageX-n,s=e.pageY-r;return{x:i,y:s}},start:function(t){var n=t.originalEvent.touches?t.originalEvent.touches[0]:t,r=e.event.special.swipe.getLocation(n);return{time:(new Date).getTime(),coords:[r.x,r.y],origin:e(t.target)}},stop:function(t){var n=t.originalEvent.touches?t.originalEvent.touches[0]:t,r=e.event.special.swipe.getLocation(n);return{time:(new Date).getTime(),coords:[r.x,r.y]}},handleSwipe:function(t,n,r,i){if(n.time-t.time<e.event.special.swipe.durationThreshold&&Math.abs(t.coords[0]-n.coords[0])>e.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold&&Math.abs(t.coords[1]-n.coords[1])<e.event.special.swipe.verticalDistanceThreshold){var s=t.coords[0]>n.coords[0]?"swipeleft":"swiperight";return l(r,"swipe",e.Event("swipe",{target:i,swipestart:t,swipestop:n}),!0),l(r,s,e.Event(s,{target:i,swipestart:t,swipestop:n}),!0),!0}return!1},eventInProgress:!1,setup:function(){var t,n=this,r=e(n),s={};t=e.data(this,"mobile-events"),t||(t={length:0},e.data(this,"mobile-events",t)),t.length++,t.swipe=s,s.start=function(t){if(e.event.special.swipe.eventInProgress)return;e.event.special.swipe.eventInProgress=!0;var r,o=e.event.special.swipe.start(t),u=t.target,l=!1;s.move=function(t){if(!o||t.isDefaultPrevented())return;r=e.event.special.swipe.stop(t),l||(l=e.event.special.swipe.handleSwipe(o,r,n,u),l&&(e.event.special.swipe.eventInProgress=!1)),Math.abs(o.coords[0]-r.coords[0])>e.event.special.swipe.scrollSupressionThreshold&&t.preventDefault()},s.stop=function(){l=!0,e.event.special.swipe.eventInProgress=!1,i.off(f,s.move),s.move=null},i.on(f,s.move).one(a,s.stop)},r.on(u,s.start)},teardown:function(){var t,n;t=e.data(this,"mobile-events"),t&&(n=t.swipe,delete t.swipe,t.length--,t.length===0&&e.removeData(this,"mobile-events")),n&&(n.start&&e(this).off(u,n.start),n.move&&i.off(f,n.move),n.stop&&i.off(a,n.stop))}},e.each({scrollstop:"scrollstart",taphold:"tap",swipeleft:"swipe.left",swiperight:"swipe.right"},function(t,n){e.event.special[t]={setup:function(){e(this).bind(n,e.noop)},teardown:function(){e(this).unbind(n)}}})}(e,this)});
```