# checkboxes - jquery mobile holding a secret

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, checkbox

I recently realized that the checkboxes take really long to respond to tapping. I am already using fastclick.js to remove the 300ms slowness caused by mobile devices waiting for double tapping.

I noticed that jQuery mobile uses some kind of technique to completely remove the lag when tapping multiple checkboxes very quickly. From what I have read elsewhere there seems to be a problem with mobiles when using click events rather than tap events, but haven't been able to find code to achieve this anywhere.

I would use a custom jQuery mobile build to take advantage of this, but what I am working on is already too heavy, so having the code that replaces click with tap for mobile, I would be really grateful!

Comment: JQM is open-source and not very secret.  The code that implements the tap event can be found [on github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/717ce8458812fb382945fec17f6298da0196bb5d/js/events/touch.js)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sometimes I forget that people in here tend to follow the phrases literally; what I meant was, that between the lines of its code, there's what I am looking for but I just can't pinpoint it. I will look into the url you posted as soon as I get home and post back. Thanks again!

Comment: Also, I would be greatful to know how exactly I am supposed to use the code posted above

Comment: Well, I tried adding the code posted above in my scripts, but had no luck. I also tried to implement a custom jquery mobile code but still nothing. At least, not without using it's own classes, etc... :/

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to use a library that handles touch events.  There are many including these:

1. [Hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) - 3kb gzipped
2. [Zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com/) - 9.2kb gzipped
3. [Quojs](http://quojs.tapquo.com/) - 6kb gzipped
4. [jGestures](http://jgestures.codeplex.com/)

Zepto is like a mini-jQuery and does a lot more than touch events, however it is designed in nice modules, one of which is the touch events module. One option if you don't want to include an entire library and you are using jQuery is to only include the touch module from zepto.  Try using [this code](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/master/src/touch.js#files) from github taking care to replace the last line from `})(Zepto)` to `})(jQuery)` and it should just work.

Some googling found this related SO question, with some good answers:
[How to use jQuery Mobile for its touch event support only (no UI enhancements)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8648596/753129)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will look into it more thoroughly later. HOWEVER, I found that the culprit was actually a jquery script (icheck.js) I used to style elements. Now I have a different problem, which I will post shortly :/