# jQuery Mobile bad behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to use the jQuery Mobile swipe feature but I'm experiencing a little problem when I include this:

http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js

and this: 
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js

The issue is a "Loading" text in the bottom of the page that is shown when i load the Mobile library.
Who knows why is it shown? I have the problem with both Chrome/Chromium and Firefox browsers.
You can take a look to my code here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/rfringuello89/yLGKT/

as you can see I used 3 not draggable but swipeable `<div></div>`

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the appropriate css for jQuery Mobile too, that should do the trick.

---

Edit: check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8F5ZT/2/), I included the css and it works fine.

This is the right way to include the libraries:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

according to the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/download/).

---

Edit2: according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12631480/1519186) by eivers88 you can use the following code to stop jQuery Mobile from initialising the page on DOM-Ready (without the need to include the css dependency):

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){$.extend(  $.mobile , {autoInitializePage: false})});</script>
```

Comment: yes but, wasn't it easier don't create this text ?
thanks, I could do it myself without include a css :D